# WiFi hotspot always turns on

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

i got a question... why does my WiFi hot spot always turn on? I already tried to reboot and everything but still doesn't work. any help? I use acer swift 1... here is my info of the computer:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64
Host: Swift SF114-32 V1.12
Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic
Uptime: 4 hours, 6 mins
Packages: 3324 (dpkg), 21 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.0.17
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: GNOME
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel Pentium Silver N5000 (4)
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 605
Memory: 2079MiB / 3739MiB

Comment: Sorry, but no one can help you without any information. What is your hardware, which Ubuntu are you using. How do does it show in your system? If you expect people to help you, share information. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1279269/edit) Your question and fill in the missing data

Comment: didn't i already say that?

Comment: Well, you edited your question 13 Minutes after I asked. Thanks for the infos, but they do not suffice. You need to check for logs concerning the network manager. And what is a Wifi Hot Spot in Ubuntu? Maybe you could describe, why you have a HotSpot and not a normal Wifi connection.

Comment: ok then, i will have to dig deep for more research

Comment: @Jay, did you ever find this out? I made the mistake of enabling hotspot a few weeks ago, now it is always on when I boot up ubuntu, I have to manually go in the settings to disable it and get a wifi connection... Thanks.